# Javascript function in asp.net

Tags: javascript

Ok, having an issue withe the return value of a function always returning "undefined"

Heres my code:

```
//called here:
var res = comms(GENSET_SN);

//the function
function comms(genserial) {
     var Result; 
     //Webservice called here
     MyServices.getCommsState(genserial, "S1", OnComplete1);

     function OnComplete1(args) {
          var Res = eval("(" + args + ")");

          if (Res == 1) {
               Result = 1;
          } else {
                Result = 0;
          }
      }
      return Result;
}
```

please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `MyServices.getCommsState(genserial, "S1", OnComplete1);` is an ajax request?

If so, the value of `Result` will be returned before it is actually set in the `OnComplete1` callback, hence `undefined`.

You will need to pass in a callback function containing the code that will use the `Result` value.

You can change the code to do this instead, note that you pass in the function to comms and then call it in `OnComplete1`:

```
comms(GENSET_SN, function(res) {
    // do whatever you need with res here!
});

//the function
function comms(genserial, callback) {
     //Webservice called here
     MyServices.getCommsState(genserial, "S1", function(args) {
         var Res = eval("(" + args + ")"); // I would change this aswell, dont use eval!
         callback(Res == 1 ? 1 : 0);
     });            
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct it is an AJAX request, how would I go about the callback function? Please excuse me ignorance im only a beginner with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You are not defining the value of Result before the function is returned. I assum getCommsState is an async function. If you need this "wrapper" function (comms) I would suggest adding a callback parameter for this too.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is Asynchronous

```
                function OnComplete1(args) {

                    var Res = eval("(" + args + ")");

                    if (Res == 1) {
                        Result = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        Result = 0;
                    }
                }
                return Result;
```

needs to be

```
              function OnComplete1(args) {

                    var Res = eval("(" + args + ")");

                    if (Res == 1) {
                        Result = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        Result = 0;
                    }

                    // RIGHT NOW - do something with result
               }
```

Notes:

1 ) eval just isn't good. Modern browsers have JSON already defined or json2.js is widely available

2 ) You might have caught this error if you formatted you code better:

```
function OnComplete1(args) {
    var Res = JSON.parse(args);

    if (Res == 1) {
        Result = 1;
    }
    else {
        Result = 0;
    }
}
return Result;
```